# Conservativity of language extension

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

It is folklore that extending a language of classical first-order logic is conservative. That is, given two languages $L \subseteq L'$, a set of $L$-sentences $\Gamma$ and an $L$-sentence $\varphi$, then any derivation (proof tree) of $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$ in $L'$ can be transformed into a derivation of $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$ in $L$.

I'm looking for a detailed elementary proof is this fact. With "elementary" I mostly mean that it cannot use the completeness theorem (since the proof of the completeness theorem I know uses this fact). I'm mostly interested in the case where the derivations use natural deduction and classical logic.

Comment: Perhaps the Craig Interpolation Theorem would help?  Or are you looking for prerequisites in order to prove CIT?  Gerhard "Taking An Approximate Stab Here" Paseman, 2018.11.23.

Comment: Yes, it seems related to the Craig Interpolation Theorem. A formulation of Craig Interpolation Theorem I know is that if $\Gamma$ proves $\varphi$, then there is a formula $\psi$ which contains only constants/function symbols/relation symbols which occur in both $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ such that $\Gamma\vdash\psi$ and $\psi\vdash\varphi$. However, since these new proof trees are still in $L'$, I don't know if that actually helps.

Comment: There is an elementary proof of this on page 14 of http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~hoyois/papers/logic.pdf (an old undegraduate essay of mine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for essentially any common proof system (Hilbert calculus, sequent calculus, natural deduction, ...).

Take a proof of $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$ in $L'$. Substitute any fixed sentence (say, $\bot$) for all instances of predicates from $L'\smallsetminus L$ in the proof, and likewise, choose a variable $v$ that does not appear anywhere in the proof, and replace all topmost occurrences of subterms $F(t_1,\dots,t_n)$, $F\in L'\smallsetminus L$, with $v$. (This includes constants, for $n=0$.) You obtain a proof in $L$, and the transformation leaves $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ unchanged.